# The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in vbscript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

My website is hosted at Web Wiz.
When i fire following query in sql server, it executes successfully.

```
select *  from Ad ,schedule,sponsor where Ad.idAd=schedule.intAd and
Ad.intSponsor=Sponsor.idSponsor and convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 111)
between convert(varchar(10), dtStartDate, 111) 
And convert(varchar(10), dtEndDate, 111)
```

But while running in **asp vbscript** it gives following error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Please advise me solution.

Comment: To format a block of code indent each line with four spaces. You can do this by hilighting the code block and pressing the {} button.

Comment: why are you converting datetime to varchar at all ? Are you trying to slow performance ? This will not be sargable

Comment: I want to keep date time unaffected from regional setting of web server and sql server.

Comment: That's a terrible excuse! You should be using the [`SMALLDATETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx), [`DATETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) or, even better, [`DATETIME2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) types (click the link for each one to see what they do). Formatting of the date can be handled in a number of ways, but the usual format is `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS` when you want to be specific.